# docker-compose mysql persistent data

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and I'm following this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose) to setup my mac (the guide is for linux but is not the point) for a PHP dev env with docker-compose.
The guide is quite good and everything seems to work correctly, there is just a part that doesn't seem to work.

If you go to Step 9 — Creating a User for MySQL, I'm running `docker-compose up` and I have these errors so I can't access the `db` container.

```
mysqld: Error on realpath() on '/var/lib/mysql-files' (Error 2 - No such file or directory)
db           | 2020-04-16T18:22:19.603226Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010095] [Server] Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /var/lib/mysql-files
db           | 2020-04-16T18:22:19.603246Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

If I remove the `- ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf` from the volumes everything seem to work but then for some reason my `laravel` db is not created.

these command is not supposed to already create a DB?

```
environment:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

another question is where the data is stored?

```
db:
...
volumes:
  - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
...

#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

how it works that driver local and what is the location of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out that the tutorial uses a wrong path, the correct path is:

```
- ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
```

and not:

```
- ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose.yml

version: '3.7'
services:
db:
image: mysql:8.0.21
container_name: dbweb
restart: always
environment:
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'deivypassword'
TZ: America/New_York
ports:
#  : < MySQL Port running inside container>
- '3306:3306'
# Where our data will be persisted
volumes:
- dbweb2:/var/lib/mysql
- ./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf

## Names our volume

volumes:
dbweb2:

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please go through [guidlines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask, answer and format your content.